# How to search CLOB first character to see if it is '<', looking for XML data

Tags: sql, oracle

**ORACLE 12.x**

Ran into an issue with our data where I see that in the past XML data is stored in a CLOB column. For some time now data is saved as Json in the CLOB. There is no other column in the DB that helps to distinguish what kind of value is stored.

How can I accurately select only rows where the CLOB is Json?
How can I accurately select only rows where the CLOB is XML?

I've been attempting to use the following but the concern is that the Json may contain the '<' character in its value. So, I think I need a way to verify that the first non space, non whitespace character is <.

```
// Find Json
SELECT *
FROM DB.COLUMN
WHERE DBMS_LOB.INSTR(CLOB_COLUMN, '<') = 0
```

And

```
// Find XML
SELECT *
FROM DB.COLUMN
WHERE DBMS_LOB.INSTR(CLOB_COLUMN, '<') >= 1
```

Comment: I would write a function that takes the CLOB input and actually does a JSON or XML conversion of it (however you do that, I don't work with these types myself). If it fails, you trap the exception with an exception handler and return a status code. if it succeeds, you return a different status code. Then simply place your function call and the status code return value you want in your WHERE clause: "WHERE myfunction(clob_column) = 1"

Comment: @PaulW any idea on what kind of performance or load hit that would cause? Dealing with millions of records.

Comment: Depending on your version, you could try `WHERE clob_column IS [NOT] JSON` (since if it's not it's presumably XML). No idea if that performs.

Comment: @edjm, will you be trying to scan millions of records with no other filters than "give me JSON/XML" ? Or are you using a narrow predicate and need to check the content as a secondary filter?

Comment: I have no indicator column or point of reference to limit the search. I just tried to find just 1 record by use of Fetch ONLY 1 and SQL Developer froze up after an hour.

Answer (score 0):

I think that json can not start with '<' character. So you can use this, to find XML columns:

```
// Find XML
SELECT *
FROM DB.COLUMN
WHERE CLOB_COLUMN like '<%>'
```

and for json:

```
// Find json
SELECT *
FROM DB.COLUMN
WHERE CLOB_COLUMN like '{%}'
```

Comment: The above does not seem to work as intended against the CLOB column. I think I found another answer dealing with use of IS JSON.

Answer (score 0):

// Find Json

```
SELECT *
FROM DB.COLUMN
WHERE CLOB_COLUMN IS JSON
```

And

// Find XML

```
SELECT *
FROM DB.COLUMN
WHERE CLOB_COLUMN IS NOT JSON
```

I did a record count against all rows in my dummy DB where the numbers add up.

- JSON records: 38575
- XML records:  4972
- Total records: 43547
- Verified total records for all in DB: 43547